# Does py2exe include imported modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml, py2exe, suds

I wrote a small script from which I want to try to compile exe and run on another computer. So the main question is about imported modules in the script. Most of them is standard of python 3.4, but few ones (suds, lxml) is installed by me. Do i need to install python and those modules on other machine or all needed files will be included in compiled distribution?

Comment: Use pyinstaller. It does and it is way easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

**From** http://www.py2exe.org/old/:

> py2exe is a Python distutils extension which converts python scripts into executable windows programs, able to run without requiring a python installation.

### UPDATE

**From** http://www.py2exe.org/old/#how-does-it-work

> py2exe uses python's modulefinder to examine your script and find all python and extension modules needed to run it. Pure python modules are compiled into .pyc or .pyo files in a temporary directory.

So you don't have to worry about the modules - be they standard or installed by you.

Comment: yap, but there not mentioned about modules.